# Iteration of time from 00:00 until 23:59 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set a time table beginning from 00:00 until 23:59

so far I got a little bit. My problem is the vba keeps rewritting the hours.

```
Sub uhrzeit()

Dim i As Integer
Dim stunde As Integer

For stunde = 1 To 24

For i = 1 To 60
  
    Cells(i, 1) = stunde
    Cells(i, 2) = i
       
Next i
    


Next stunde
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another option:

Sub uhrzeit()

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim stunde As Long

i = 1
    For stunde = 0 To 23
    
        For j = 0 To 59
            Activesheet.Cells(i, 1) = stunde
            Activesheet.Cells(i, 2) = j
            i = i + 1
        Next j
    
    Next stunde

End Sub
```

Essentially, you want a separate counter to track the row you're writing to and then to increment it after you've written to that row.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy: You don't advance (by 60) for each hour, instead you are (re-)writing the `Cells(i, 1)` 24 times.

Note that you always should tell VBA on which sheet you want to work, and that the usage of `Integer` is deprecated (use `Long` instead). And you probably want your hour run from 0 to 23, not from 1 to 24 and the minutes from 0 to 59.

```
Const rowOffset = 2
Dim stunde As Long, min as Long
With ActiveSheet ' Or something like ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For stunde = 0 To 23
        For min = 0 To 59
            Dim row As Long
            row = stunde * 60 + min + rowOffset
            .Cells(row, 1) = stunde
            .Cells(row, 2) = min
       Next min
    Next stunde
End With
```

**Update** Added `rowOffset` - obviously you can't write into cell 0

Answer (score 1):

### Time: Hours and Minutes

[image]

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub UhrZeit()
    
    Const ERSTE_ZEILE As Long = 2
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    Dim Min As Long, Stunde As Long, Zeile As Long

    For Stunde = 0 To 23
        For Min = 0 To 59
            Zeile = (Stunde * 60) + Min + ERSTE_ZEILE
            ws.Cells(Zeile, "A").Value = Stunde
            ws.Cells(Zeile, "B").Value = Min
        Next Min
    Next Stunde

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Minute` is the name of a function in VBA. While this will work, the definition of `Minute` as Long will hide that function.